# Changing command to exclude subfolders

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line

I am using this command line

```
 for /r  /d %F in (.) do @dir /b "%F" | findstr "^" >nul || echo %~fF
```

to find empty folders.

However this command is working for subfolders too. How can I change it to exclude the sub folders?

Comment: Could you please expand upon your definition of 'empty folders'? Are you seeking child directories of the current directory which contain no files? or child directories of the current directory which contain no files, and no directories?

Comment: I am seeking only for current directory with empty folders ( having no files). Isn't it possible to just see the folder size as 0 KB instead of scanning each folder?

Comment: Vishwas, I have updated my exiting answer with an **[EDIT /]** to cater for your clarified information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `/r` from the command, use this:

```
for /d %F in (*) do @dir /b "%F" | findstr "^" >nul || echo %~fF
```

Answer (score 1):

As this is clearly for the current directory, I would off a slightly different alternative. This is because `For /D` doesn't pick up every directory, it ignores hidden ones, and `Dir /B` alone, does not select every file and directory.

```batch-file
For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %G In ('Dir /B/AD') Do @Dir /B/A "%G" 2>NUL|%__AppDir__%find.exe /V "">NUL||Echo %G
```

*If you prefer a relative path for your results, just use `Echo .\%G` instead*

The answer uses `2>NUL` to redirect any `File Not Found` error messages to the NUL device. It also uses `find.exe` as an alternative to `findstr.exe`, to ensure that the answer is less similar than the existing one, and because you don't really need its special functionality.

To get more information about the commands used, please open a [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) window, and enter the following commands as necessary:

- `For` command `for /?`  or `help for`
- `Dir` command `dir /?`  or `help dir`
- `Find` command `find /?` or `help find`
- `Echo` command `echo /?` or `help echo`

*The `%__AppDir__%` variable is a special dynamically created variable, the content of which cannot be modified. This will always point to your appropriate `\System32` directory, whether running under a 32-bit or 64-bit process. The result is that the command will not fail to run the appropriate version of Microsoft's `find.exe` in its correct location, eliminating a failure, should your standard environment become corrupted or modified. In addition, I used the `.exe` extension for `find`, because it is not an internal command and should your `%PATHEXT%` variable become corrupted or modified, the command would still work as intended.*

---

**[Edit /]**

As you've further clarified that you're looking for those without files, not without files and directories, I'd offer this alternative, using the Microsoft's `where.exe`, [windows-vista](/questions/tagged/windows-vista) minumum:

```batch-file
For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %G In ('Dir /B/AD') Do @%__AppDir__%where.exe /Q "%G":*>Nul||Echo %G
```

*If you prefer a relative path for your results, just use `Echo .\%G` instead*

To get more information about the `where` command, please open a [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) window, and enter either the following command, `where /?`, or this one `help where`.